# Android java.io.FileNotFoundException No such file or > directory, although permissions are granted

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-permissions, fast-android-networking

I am trying to upload an image that was previously taken from the camera, and I can confirm that I am granted the permission to `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I am using  minSdkVersion 23 in Gradle.

Th Uri of the image is saved in a database, and when I try to use this Uri to put it into an ImageView.

Here is where I request to access the file at the given Uri

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context ,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context as Activity,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ
                    )

        }
    } else {
        val imageArray  = post.postImages
        uploadImages(imageArray!!)

    }
```

The Uri is kept within a JSONArray, so I remove the unwanted characters and prepare the file for upload:

```
  val singleImage = imageUri
  val substr = singleImage.replace("\"","").split("file://").last()
  println("substr $substr")
  var finalFile: File? = File(substr)

  if(finalFile.exists()){
        println("finalFile $finalFile")
  }else{
      println("finalFile does not exist")
   }
```

> I/System.out: substr /storage/emulated/0/customFolder/picture.jpg
>
> I/System.out: finalFile /storage/emulated/0/customFolder/picture.jpg

Here is the print out to check if the files does exist, and it looks like it doesn't.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:/storage/emulated/0/customFolder/picture.jpg (No such file or directory)

Although when going through the files on my device I do see the image, and when using that same Uri to put it into an imageview, the image does show up.

The following step is uploading the file (I am using my upload is handled by the Library [Fast Android Networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking))

```
 AndroidNetworking.upload("http://myUrl.com")
                   .addMultipartFile("file", finalFile)
                   .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                   .build()
```

Considering my File is considered non existent, I get a crash with the error message once the File begins uploading:

> FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/customFolder/picture.jpg (No such file or
>   directory)

and I get this error message:

> error: com.androidnetworking.error.ANError:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed

I'm not sure why the File isn't being recognized and/or created. Is anyone able to identify why my file isn't getting created?

Comment: You haven't actually stated the problem in your question. In the title you say you are encountering a `FileNotFoundException`, but so far you've only posted the part of your code that works. You need to add the code that's actually causing the problem, and point out where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @LeoAso , I've added more details regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I am experiencing was caused by a bug using the Fast Android Networking library. I have flagged this [issue](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking/issues/430) to the developer, he is apparently working on a fix.